# Post receive pull hook on gitblit server

Tags: git, groovy, githooks, gitblit

I need to set up post-receive hook script on Gitblit server that will pull changes to a website on the same server. In a bash script, command would look something like this:

```
sudo git --work-tree=/var/www/html/mysite --git-dir=/var/www/html/mysite/.git pull
```

But as I understand, Gitblit uses groovy hooks scripts, and I'm completely new to this. Can someone please help me with creating a groovy script for this, or at least direct me to some good examples or tutorial for Groovy.

Thanks

Comment: do you just need this command "in groovy" or do you lack the general understanding how such a thing is done with gitblit?. the groovy code is `["sudo", "git", "--work-tree...", ...].execute()`

Comment: Both. I just heard of Groovy yesterday, and all examples I saw seem too complex. Basically, I need a groovy script that will do that command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone needs help with groovy, here is my groovy script:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger

def res = ["git", "--work-tree=/var/www/html/mysite", "--git-dir=/var/www/html/mysite/.git", "pull"].execute()

println res.err.text
println res.text
```